# Which sketch was this?

Tags: serial, esp32, sketch

With ESP32 being so plentiful here (3 more for Christmas) I am at a loss to determine which sketch I used for a particular unit. Has anyone devised a record keeping scheme or even a serial monitor feedback with the sketch details available when plugged back in to the PC?

Comment: What information do you want to see there exactly? You could just do a Serial print with some custom message (defined by you) inside `setup()`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I set up a precompile trigger that will run a shell script that grabs the current git hash and puts it in a file as a #define.  From my sketch I print that.  Then I know which file and which version is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Early in setup() I print one line to the terminal with the .ino file's name, revision, and date. I keep all projects under source-code control which maintains that line without any effort from me, as long as I've included the small snippet of data and  and the Serial.println() call to print it.

Update:

> Can you show some code how you include the automatic revision identification into the Arduino Build Chain?

Here's an example. Note that the build-chain isn't modified; everything happens in the source code, RCS, in my case. You'll probably have to tweak the keyword that gets the revision data, ($Id$ in RCS) for whatever source control you use. If you aren't using source control, you could print the compile-time macros suggested by @DataFiddler.

```
/*
 * Macro to tell ::println() & family to expact a pointer to Flash memory
 * #define this in your library's local.h file, or where ever you'd 
 * put your personal, site-unique, or non-public macros like your 
 * WiFi password:
 * 
 * #define FLSTR_HLP(str) (const __FlashStringHelper *)str
 * (Look up __FlashStringHelper for more information)
 * 
 */
// ----------------------------------
// Your .ino file would start here:

#include <local.h>                        // gets the above #define

// Define one of these in each .ino file:
// const char IdString[] PROGMEM = $Id$
// RCS expands or updates it to something like this,
//  every time you check out any version:
//  (Other source control systems will have similar facilities)
const char IdString[] PROGMEM = "$Id: HowTo_IdString.ino,v 1.1 2023-12-26 18:16:06-05 jrobert Exp $";   // def an IdString in Flash



void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial.print("");
   Serial.println(FLSTR_HLP(IdString));   // prints the IdString from Flash

   // .. more setup ..
}

void loop() {
   Serial.print(F("Run time: "));
   Serial.println(millis());
   delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you show some code how you include the automatic revision identification into the Arduino Build Chain?

Comment: `Serial.println(__DATE__);
  Serial.println(__TIME__);`  shows compilation date and time. Should be close to source file save time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a simple way of identification, use some of the compiler's [predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros)* as automagic source of information:

```cpp
void setup() {
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("(");
  Serial.print(__VERSION__);
  Serial.print(") ");
  Serial.print(__FILE__);
  Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.print(__DATE__);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(__TIME__);
}

void loop() {
}
```

The output of the sketch is:

```
(7.3.0) /home/XXXXXXXX/name_of_sketch.ino: Dec 27 2023, 23:03:58
```

*) In my case (Arduino IDE version 1.8.19) the version of G++ is 7.3.0.